# Regex catch only the second occurence

Tags: python, regex

Hi im using this regex pattern:

```
.*@.*\:.*#\s(.*)
```

on this text:

```
t@ubuntu:/opt/test# cd /opt/blabla/¢ ־.P־.®Z[P§..P.#ְ״toot@bubuntu:/opt/testo# nano /etc/d× ־.P־.®Z[_§..
```

and the regex catch only

```
nano /etc/d× ־.P־.®Z[_§..
```

I'm trying to catch only the command `cd /opt/blabla` and `nano /etc/d`
why the regex don't catch the `cd /opt/blabla`?

EDIT:
i tried to first converting all the non ascii characters to spaces and now the text looks like:

```
't@ubuntu:/opt/volatility# cd /opt/Kazaar/     .P  .     Z[P  ..P.#    root@ubuntu:/opt/Kazaar# nano /etc/d     .P  .     Z[_  ..'
```

every command ending with space so i change the regex to:

```
""".*@.*\:.*#\s(.*)\s"""
```

but still it capture only the nano command without cd.

Comment: I suggest you have a play with e.g. https://regex101.com/r/nP0mW2/1

Comment: Because it doesn't match the regex, where do you see `@` in the expected match? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](https://ideone.com/PMlGIe), is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular use case, with non-ASCII characters, the following regex will catch the full command:

```
[^#]*#\s([\x00-\x7F]*)
```

The Ubuntu command prompt is separated from the command by a `#` symbol.
The reason we begin with `[^#]` instead of `.*` is because `.*` is too greedy: it'll consume all instances of `#` except for the last one. So we have to explicitly tell the regex not to match any `#` characters at first.

The regex above will catch the command name and any number of ASCII arguments, so you should use it for the original version of your code (don't replace all the non-ASCII characters with spaces). Here's the output:

```
cd /opt/blabla/
nano /etc/d
```

It's also possible, with a slightly more complicated regex, to parse UNIX commands and command prompts, when they're separated only by whitespace. So after you'd removed the non-ASCII characters and trimmed any excessive whitespace, you'd have a line that looked like this:

```
t@ubuntu:/opt/test# cd /opt/blabla/ toot@bubuntu:/opt/testo# nano /etc/d
```

And you could then use lookahead assertions to match only the commands and their arguments:

```
[^\x64 ]+@[^#]+#\s*(.+?(?=\s+[^\x64 ]+@|\s*$))
```

Finally, and most complex of all, if you had an inconsistent line, where some commands were separated by whitespace, and others by non-ASCII characters, you could use this:

```
[^\x64 ]+@[^#]+#\s*([\x00-\x7F]+(?=[^\x00-\x7F]+|\s+[^\x64 ]+@|\s*$))
```

The first portion `[^\x64 ]+@[^#]+#` covers the Ubuntu prompt. Then there's arbitrary whitespace `\s*`, then the group matches as many ASCII characters as it can without meeting any non ASCII characters, the end of the line, or another UNIX prompt. This means it will also work for UNIX commands that take multiple arguments, like `mv` or `cp`

Answer (score 0):

Your match is too greedy try [this](https://regex101.com/r/dD8vH0/1):

```
/.*?@.*?\:.*?#\s(.*? .*?) /
```

Why tries to get the minimum amount of characters before a match.  This assumes that there are two "words" after the # separated by a space, ending with a space.

It would be better if your text contained a CR character to separate out the commands as there is no way to determine the command and parameters you are looking for with 100% accuracy without sanitizing the data because it is impossible to determine the "end of the line".

Comment: i tried this it capture only "cd" and "nano" i want to capture the full command

Comment: Did you try the link?

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.5

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: string = 't@ubuntu:/opt/test# cd /opt/blabla/¢ ־.P־.®Z[P§..P.#ְ״toot@bubuntu:/opt/testo# nano /etc/d× ־.P־.®Z[_§..'

In [3]: pattern = '\w+\ (\/\w+)+'

In [4]: list(re.finditer(pattern,string))
Out[4]: 
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(20, 34), match='cd /opt/blabla'>,
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(80, 91), match='nano /etc/d'>]
```

You can access the match via `.group(0)`

```
In [5]: list(re.finditer(pattern,string))[0].group(0)
Out[5]: 'cd /opt/blabla'

In [6]: list(re.finditer(pattern,string))[1].group(0)
Out[6]: 'nano /etc/d'
```